# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException while ArrayList from Sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, android-alertdialog

I'm getting error below while on button click

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.gor.hocam.MainActivity.getListitem(MainActivity.java:329)
at com.gor.hocam.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:222)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My Button that i clicked is (MainActivity.java:222 is the first line below);

```
getListitem();
System.out.println(dersadilist.size());

String[] arrRecords = dersadilist.toArray(new String[dersadilist.size()]);

int arr[] = new int[derskodulist.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < derskodulist.size(); i++) {
    arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(derskodulist.get(i));
}



new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
    .title("Son Çözdüğünüz Dersler:")
    .items(arrRecords)
    .itemsIds(arr)
    .itemsCallback(new MaterialDialog.ListCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, which + ": " + text + ", ID = " + view.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).show();
```

Here my getListitem ( which is = (MainActivity.java:329);

```
    public void getListitem() {

    List<Scoredata> score = db.getAllContacts();

    for (Scoredata sc : score) {
        dersidler = String.valueOf(sc.getId());
        dersadlari = sc.getName();
        topscore = sc.getScore();
        derskodlari = sc.getKodu();
        //sc.getScore();

        dersidlist.add(dersidler);
        dersadilist.add(dersadlari);
        scorelist.add(topscore);
        derskodulist.add(dersadlari);
    }



}
```

Thats my Scoredata;

```
public class Scoredata {

int id;
String name, kodu, score;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getKodu() {
    return kodu;
}
public void setKodu(String kodu) {
    this.kodu = kodu;
}
public String getScore() {
    return score;
}
public void setScore(String score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public Scoredata(String name, String kodu, String score) {
    super();

    this.name = name;
    this.kodu = kodu;
    this.score = score;
}
public Scoredata() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

}
```

And getAllContacts on my DbHighestScore;

```
public List<Scoredata> getAllContacts() {
    List<Scoredata> scoreList = new ArrayList<Scoredata>();



    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " ORDER BY id DESC";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Scoredata score = new Scoredata();
            score.setId(Integer.valueOf(cursor.getString(0)));
            score.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            score.setKodu(cursor.getString(2));
            score.setScore(cursor.getString(3));


            scoreList.add(score);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // return contact list
    return scoreList;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your "db" is null when you access it.

Comment: Which line is exactly 329 of `MainActivity`?

Comment: @cool ; i'm sure its not
@Suhas; public void getListitem() {

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `db` object is not null and the collection object `score` is not null before parsing through it

```
public void getListitem() {
    if(db != null){
    List<Scoredata> score = db.getAllContacts();
    if(score!= null){
    for (Scoredata sc : score) {
        dersidler = String.valueOf(sc.getId());
        dersadlari = sc.getName();
        topscore = sc.getScore();
        derskodlari = sc.getKodu();
        //sc.getScore();

        dersidlist.add(dersidler);
        dersadilist.add(dersadlari);
        scorelist.add(topscore);
        derskodulist.add(dersadlari);
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: score coming from getAllContacts is certainly not null because the array is initialized in that method. Checking null of "db" is not a good idea.

Comment: I don't get any error but  it doesn't show results

Comment: That means either `db` is null or `db.getAllContacts()` is not returning anything. Put a debug point or log statement to check which is actually null

Comment: i've added else's to db != null and score != null since i don't have any idea how to put a debug or log statement, it shows me db null. But i'm sure my db is not null as i show other columns of same table in another activity

Comment: Can you paste the entire code of the MainActivity, is the `db` object a class variable or a variable from shared object?

Comment: @HalideYildiz , DB objects should ideally be created in onCreate() function of that activity. If its created else where, please go through the activity life cycle to understand how the resources are shredded

Comment: i posted it as a new answer